# Técnicas para levantar requisitos e escrever casos de uso

Tags: modelagem, engenharia-de-software, casos-de-uso

Faz um tempo vi um curso do Lynda.com chamado "Foundations of Programming: Object Oriented Design" e o cara do curso deu uma lista de 5 passos para criar um modelo de domínio:

- Coletar requerimentos
- Descrever o sistema (com casos de uso)
- Identificar os objetos principais
- Identificar as relações entre os objetos principais
- Fazer um diagrama de classes

Até aí tudo bem, gostei muito da forma que ele propõe para fazer o modelo de domínio, mas eu ainda estou com bastante dúvida na coleta de requerimentos e na descrição do sistema com casos de uso. Existem técnicas para um programador que trabalha sozinho fazer isso com sucesso? Existem também exemplos reais?

Digo isso porque eu trabalho na maioria com aplicativos web e intranets, mas os exemplos que eu achei até agora são sobre caixa eletrônico de banco e coisas do tipo. São coisas interessantes, mas queria ver algo mais próximo do que eu trabalho, pra poder me basear.

Comment: Sugiro que você dê uma lida no Project Management Body of Knowledge, também conhecido como PMBOK. A etapa da coleta de requisitos é só uma pequena parte entre as 10 áreas de conhecimento que um projeto pode possuir. O pouco que você absorver de lá já é um grande passo para os projetos que você tocar futuramente.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão @rodrigorigotti, vou dar uma olhada sim. Esse livro é focado em equipes ou para um programador sozinho também serve?

Comment: Na verdade o PMBOK tem como público alvo o gerente de projetos, mas qualquer um pode ser gerente de projetos do seu próprio projeto. :) Boa sorte!

Comment: (Quatro anos depois...) Procure cursos online de UML como por exemplo na Udemy.com, alguns deles são focados em aplicações web.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A teoria é linda, se não fosse teoria.

na prática

1. nunca se consegue coletar todos os requisitos de um sistema no começo dele, porque o uso do sistema leva os usuários a refletirem sobre novos usos, sem contar com o fato de que eles se lembram de novos detalhes.
2. abordagens "ágeis" vão tentar te vender a idéia de que você pode grudar no cliente e ir extraindo interativamente os requisitos, negociando a cada delivery um conjunto de funcionalidades que "agregue valor" (coff coff). Eu acho bastante questionável que um cliente tope pagar por iterações sem saber o que ele vai ter ao final de um determinado prazo, talvez daí a grande maioria dos contratos ainda se manterem de escopo fechado. Acho igualmente questionável que o cliente tenha a disponibilidade de participar do projeto como a agilidade advoga, mas vale tentar. Na prática, clientes sentem que adivinhar o que ele quer faz parte do pacote que ele está pagando, afinal, é o tempo dele.

Dado que sistema nenhum começa a ser desenvolvido sem uma noção mínima inicial de escopo, e dado que a abordagem de tentar coletar o máximo de especificação desde o começo não seja perfeita pela natureza dinâmica da engenharia de software e dado que as abordagens ágeis vendem a idéia correta de que o cliente deve considerar o software como um **serviço** de desenvolvimento e não como um **produto** que custa X para ficar pronto com preço definido desde o início, o que nos resta?

1. Identificar logo no início quais são as funcionalidades MAIS IMPORTANTES e focar nelas desde o começo, pelo fato de que se você atrasar (e vc provavelmente vai), fica mais fácil o projeto sobreviver se as funcionalidades principais forem implementadas desde o início
2. Obter do cliente comprometimento quanto aos requisitos, formalizando-os sempre que possível e priorizando, de forma que vc tenha alguma moeda de negociação (vc vai precisar)
3. Obter desde o início os critérios de aceite do sistema, que são mais importantes e definem melhor o que o sistema deve realmente fazer do que a especificação inicial. Na verdade, se vc puder focar no critério de aceite como o critério onde o projeto e os pagamentos acabam desde o início do projeto, tanto melhor. Caso contrário, indica que seu cliente não sabe bem o que quer e que o projeto deve ser encarado como um serviço e não como um produto.

UPDATE - só complementando, vc pediu técnicas. A técnica mais importante é saber ouvir. E depois de uns bons anos, eu percebi que o melhor livro que eu conheço para ensinar empatia e a saber ouvir é este livro, que embora não pareça poder ser aplicado a engenharia de software, eu acho perfeitamente possível. [http://www.amazon.com/How-Talk-Kids-Will-Listen/dp/1451663889](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451663889)

Answer (score 3):

Concordo com o Leo em que a teoria é diferente da prática, sendo que a resposta toda é muito boa.

## Teoria vs Prática

Temos que tomar cuidado.

Muitas teorias são criadas para depois serem implementadas e testadas na prática. Pode ser que funcionem ou não.

Mas no caso da Engenharia de Software, o que ocorre em geral é o inverso. Muito da teoria veio da observação da prática ou emprestado de outras áreas de conhecimento, tais como procedimentos de fábricas ou gerenciamento de projetos.

O problema é que essas coisas não funcionam da mesma forma, afinal não se desenvolve um software da mesma forma que se fabrica um automóvel em linhas de produção ou se constrói um prédio.

## Analogias

Embora não sejam perfeitas, muitas analogias com essas outras áreas nos ajudam a entender o que estamos fazendo.

Da mesma forma, um passo-a-passo como o descrito na pergunta não consiste numa regra fixa a ser seguida, mas numa abstração do que realmente é feito.

Em outras palavras, não é como num livro de receitas ou um manual de montagem onde você executa cada passo e obtém o produto final. Pense na teoria de Engenharia de Software sobre uma tentativa de explicitar ou descrever o que muitas vezes fazemos sem mesmo entender.

## Exemplo

Suponha que você teve uma ideia para um sistema interno para sua empresa que vai melhorar um determinado processo.

Você vai até o responsável pela área e faz algumas perguntas para entender como realmente as coisas funciona.

Depois volta para sua mesa e escreve um texto dizendo o que o sistema poderia fazer para efetivamente melhorar o processo.

Então você volta para falar com o responsável e explica sua proposta, isto é, como você pretende fazer o trabalho dele mais fácil ou efetivo, economizar esforço, diminuir erros, ou qualquer coisa nessa linha.

Imagine que ele gostou da ideia e lhe diz que ficaria grato em trabalhar com você para tornar isso real.

Nesse ponto você volta para sua mesa e gasta um ou dois dias esboçando melhor sua ideia, criando modelos das telas, talvez modelando o banco de dados e, no fim, monta um pequeno protótipo bem simples,

Agora você chama o responsável e mostra o que fez. Imagine que ele gostou, acha que está no caminho certo e apenas dá algumas dicas sobre alguns detalhes que ficariam melhor de um outro jeito.

Finalmente, você despenderia mais uma ou duas semanas para melhorar o protótipo, polir a interface, colocar alguma segurança e disponibilizar a primeira versão do produto.

O responsável então começa a usar com sua equipe, verifica que o resultado foi positivo e a partir daí ele vai começar a solicitar algumas melhorias, pequenos ajustes e novas funcionalidades para melhorar ainda mais o ganho obtido.

## Explicação

Tudo o que descrevi acima tentando não usar termos técnicos é exatamente como poderia funcionar um projeto usando os mesmos passos descritos na pergunta, mas com juma abordagem ágil.

Note que mesmo no projeto ágil você tem a análise de requisitos, descrição do sistema em estórias de usuário, pensar nos objetos que vão compor a solução e fazer esses objetos funcionarem.

As principais diferenças são:

- Talvez não seja necessário gastar muito tempo fazendo diagramas a **não ser que isso seja relevante para o seu entendimento do problema**
- No processo ágil não se tenta descobrir tudo o que o sistema deve fazer para sempre e sempre, mas focar numa ideia inicial que resolve o problema mais crítico, testar se isso funciona, receber o *feedback* do usuário e iterar novamente, isto é, voltar ao primeiro passo para criar uma nova versão do sistema melhor e com mais funcionalidades
- O foco é em atender as necessidades do cliente e não simplesmente em criar um modelo computacional e diagramas bonitos

## Considerações

Use os conceitos da Engenharia de Software para entender os princípios do desenvolvimento de software e então use as técnicas de engenharia ou de gerenciamento que contribuam para melhorar o seu trabalho.

Às vezes, quando o ambiente de trabalho é caótico, é recomendável adotar algum modelo de desenvolvimento existente. Mas, em geral, o ideal é não tentar seguir um livro-texto e sim adaptar os métodos disponíveis que sejam relevantes no seu caso para então tentar fazer um trabalho mais efetivo.

O que não der certo deve ser simplesmente descartado. Por exemplo, eu recomendo você tentar fazer um diagrama de classes simples, sem gastar muito tempo pensando em absolutamente todos os possíveis relacionamentos e atributos. Depois de um tempo você vai perceber o quanto esse diagrama foi útil ou não e, no próximo ciclo vai ter mais segurança para decidir isso.